# Can we do transaction using UI WEB VIEW iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

We have a full fledged website that has a checkout mechanism it,using which users can buy items,we decided to make an iOS app that will simply open the home page of the website under the UI web view of iOS.

I just wanted to ask is it acceptable by Apple as we are not using in app purchases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your app will most likely be rejected.

From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality):

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, unique, are *simply web sites bundled as Apps*, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may
>   be rejected

If you are selling physical goods or services that are not consumed within the app you cannot use in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

YES it is possible but I would strongly recommend you not to Use it.

This is apple Guideline for uploaded apps

> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected